# Hacer un for en medio de un append

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hola buenas noches sigo encontrandome baches ya que no controlo mucho JavaScript, pero bueno así se aprende.

Bien quiero hacer un `for` en medio de un `append` eso es posible?

```
$('#zonaProductos').on( 'click', '.seleccionProducto', function(){
        var prod = $(this).attr("data-id");
        var url = '/ficha-producto-pizza';
        
        $.ajax({
            headers: { 'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content') },
            type: "GET",
            url: url,
            data: {'prod': prod},
            success: function (elProducto){
                $('#zonaProductos').append('<div class="modal left modalLat" id="'+ elProducto.producto.slug +'" tabindex="-1"  role="dialog" aria-labelledby="'+ elProducto.producto.slug +'" aria-hidden="true" data-backdrop="false" style="background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)";>\
                    <div class="modal-dialog myModal" role="document">\
                        <div class="modal-content contentModal">\
                            <a class="cerrar_modal_lateral"><i class="fas fa-times"></i></a>\
                            <h2 class="h2Titulo">'+ elProducto.producto.name +'</h2>\
                            <p class="pParrafo">'+ elProducto.producto.descripcion +'</p>\                         
                              <h5 class="h5Elige">INGREDIENTE EXTRA</h5>\
                              <div id="ingredientes" class="btn-group btn-group-toggle row" data-toggle="buttons">\
                              </div>\
                            </div>\
                        </div>\
                    </div>\
                </div>');
                
                
                //Una vez creado el modal ya podemos hacer show
                $("#" + elProducto.producto.slug +"").modal("show");

                $.each(elProducto , function(index, ingredientes) { 
                    for(i = 0; i < ingredientes.length; i++){
                        console.log(ingredientes);
                        $('#ingredientes').html('<label class="btn btnIngredient">\
                            <input type="checkbox" name="ingredientes[]" value="'+ ingredientes[i].nombre +'" autocomplete="off"> '+ ingredientes[i].nombre +'\
                        </label>');
                    }                    
                });
                //Llamamos a la función para darle ancho a la ventana de modal
                abreMenu(); 
            },
        });
    });
```

Lo que estoy generando con la respuesta del AJAX es un modal, dentro de el hay mucho contenido estático que lo creo sin problemas, pero ahora tengo que iterar en la `div id="ingredientes"` todos los ingredientes que tengo en la base de datos. Pero tal como lo tengo ahora, solo me saca un ingrediente (cuando hay 28) en el primer modal que abro, y si abro el resto no muestra.

No se si al estar el `for` dentro de un evento click es un problema, que opinais?

Si lo hago con `append` en lugar de con `html` si la primera vez que abro la ventana me muestra todos, pero si doy a otra sale vacio, pero si vuelvo a la que si me los mostró me los duplica por tantas ventanas haya abierto, parece que solo me lo muestra en una ventana modal y no se porque.

Comment: En primer lugar creo que te sería más fácil si usas *template strings* y creo que tu lógica esta mal, creo que debería de ser "un append dentro de un for" `for(..){append()}` :)

Comment: Hola @Christian justo edite mi pregunta diciendo lo que pasa con `append`. Se que no estara bien estoy practicando

Comment: Sería muy ilustrativo si mostraras un ejemplo del resultado obtenido en tu llamada Ajax y del modal que deseas lograr a partir de ese resultado. Tal como está tu pregunta es difícil entender lo que pretendes lograr. Saludos

Comment: Hola @MauricioContreras ya lo solucione, perdona que estaba cenando. Al final el problema es que solo detectaba una ventana modal, voy a añadir una respuesta, gracias por tu atención!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Publico mi propia solución, después de varias pruebas encontré que el problema es que solo detecta una ventana modal. Por eso a mi <div id="ingredientes"` le hice lo siguiente:

Añadiendo el `slug` a mi etiqueta `ingredientes` consigo diferenciar en que ventana modal estoy.

```
<div id="ingredientes_'+ elProducto.producto.slug +'" class="btn-group btn-group-toggle row ingredie" data-toggle="buttons"
```

Luego una vez cargado toda la ventana modal hago lo siguiente, del mismo modo hago que lo cargue en la etiqueta `ingredientes correcta`:

```
$.each(elProducto , function(index, ingredientes) { 
                    for(i = 0; i < ingredientes.length; i++){
                        $('#ingredientes_'+ elProducto.producto.slug +'').append('<label class="btn btnIngredient">\
                            <input type="checkbox" name="ingredientes[]" value="España" autocomplete="off"> '+ ingredientes[i].nombre +'\
                        </label>');
                    }                    
                });
```

Y cada vez que se hace clic en `.seleccionProducto` vacio el html para que no se vaya duplicando cada vez que entro de nuevo. Como son ids dinamicas según el slug, le añadi la clase `ingredie` así los vacio sin problemas.

```
$('.ingredie').empty();
```

Answer (score 0):

Respondiendo estrictamente a la pregunta, si es posible, por ejemplo ejecutando una función:

```js
document.getElementById("div").append((()=>{let tmp = ""; for( let i = 0; i<5; i++){tmp +=" contenido "+i} return tmp + " --- ";})());


document.getElementById("div").append([5,6,7].map(e=>"contenido "+e).join());
```

```html
<div id="div">
  contenido inicial.
</div>
```